# How did Skye's watch work here?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

[Spoilers ahead...based on material up to Season 2, Episode 11]

Electronics do not work in the underground Kree city in Episode 10. This is very important to subsequent events: no robots, no communication, no gadgets.

Yet, in the very next episode Fitz analyzes the metrics recorded by the watch Skye was wearing.

The data he recovers turns out to be a crucial plot point, as it leads Fitz to cover up Skye's transformation from the rest of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Is there an explanation for why electric flashlights didn't work, but Skye's electronic watch did?

Comment: I seem to recall Jemma's radio working down there too (during cleanup).

Comment: Is this clear that the watch wasn't Steampunk?

Comment: @phantom42, I'm not sure about the radio, but I *do* remember a flash bulb (for a camera).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think the temple may be reacting to threats, not electronics.

---

Fitzsimmons send the Dwarves into the tunnels, and that seems to be the sole basis from which they conclude that electronics don’t work in the city. (Which is not unreasonable given the high stress.) But they don’t take any more electronics into the city to test or refute this theory.

When they get back to the Bus, Fitz posits the idea that the City is defending itself:

> Fitz: What if it reacts when it senses a threat? I mean, it's the same way the Obelisk would when somebody touches it. I mean, we we both know that alien materials react negatively to human biology.

We know the city treats Skye and Raina differently to the others – for example, when they meet Mack, he leads them to the Temple rather than attacking them. Perhaps it leaves her watch alone because it’s worn by a trusted person?

Comment: Details may be a little sketchy; I haven’t rewatched anything from the first half of season 2. But I think this is correct in broad strokes.

Comment: Clever. Too bad you aren't writing these ;)

Comment: @PaulDraper If they let a pedant like me write the show, all the details would be perfect, but I’d probably do something silly like forget to include a plot. ;-)